# how to use variable value such as n or i in my Code?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java & I have a question about this code , I am sorry that my question sounds a little bit stupid :)

```
class Student4{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    Student4(int i,String n){  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
    }  
    void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name);}  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Student4 s1 = new Student4(111,"Karan");  
        Student4 s2 = new Student4(222,"Aryan");  
        s1.display();  
        s2.display();  
    }  
}
```

In this code , inside the constructor the variable id has given this value i
and name = n

but in display() method I tried to use n & i like this

```
void display(){System.out.println(i+" "+n);}
```

but I got error :( !

so what's the point of giving the variable name a variable value such as n , if I can't use it at all ?

Comment: `i` and `n` only exist inside the constructor.

Comment: Scope of `ì` and `n` is within the constructor and cannot be accessed anywhere else

Comment: Here id and name is global variable and i and n are private variable for that constructor that's why you can used it in constructor only.

Comment: Refer http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html to understand why you are getting that error.

Comment: You should post error detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in display() method I tried to use n & i like this

```
void display(){System.out.println(i+" "+n);}
```

They are the local to the constructor. You cannot access them. Their scope is limited to the constructor and not visible outside the constructor.

Try this:

```
void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name);}
```

The variable `id` and `name` are will be accessible, because they are the class member which holds the data for a object.

A better way will be using them with the `this` reference.

```
void display(){System.out.println(this.id+" "+this.name);}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `n` are both parameters to the `Student4` constructor.  You cannot access these variables outside of the constructor.  This is an issue related to *scope*.  This is something you should read up on first as it is a very basic programming concept.  See here:

http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable i and n is inside the constructor of the class. So you cannot use it outside of your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In display method you want to print state of Student. So you should use class attributes i.e. **id** and **name**.

**i** and **n** are local variables of the constructor. So you can use them only inside constructor method (and not outside).